# Searching for info on an idiom for expressing extent

Tags: idioms, hyperbole

I have the impression of an idiom used to express the exaggerated extent of something that follows the pattern "It was (some measure) if it was (other measure)".  For example, to express the size of a fish one caught, "It was three feet long if it was a mile!"

I'd like to know more about the origin and usage of this idiom.  Unfortunately, I can't find a specific example of it, and it's hard to do a web search for this specific construction.

My questions are,

0. Is this a real idiom, or am I making it up?  If it's regional, it's likely Midwestern or Southern U.S.
1. If it is real, is there a way to refer to this type of expression that would allow me to search for more info or for examples?
2. And, if anyone happens to know anything about it in particular, I'd welcome more insight on it.  In particular, I'm interested in how it came to be used, since when parsed literally, expressions of this form don't really make any sense.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your example gets the expression backward; usually the "if-clause" contains the less surprising statement (as in the page linked by @livresque).

Comment: @livresque That's exactly it, thank you